# Undefined function 'field_widget_instance

Tags: drupal-8, drupal-modules

Getting error in Drupal 9 Migration custom module

```
function sun_link_field_process($element, $form_state, $complete_form) {
  $instance = field_widget_instance($element, $form_state);
  $settings = $instance['settings'];
```

Comment: What is the error that you're getting? Please edit the question to provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

This is Drupal 7 field API, it just needs converting to D9.x.  Note too, it's very different now and needs to be in a class and use [Annotations](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/plugin-api/annotations-based-plugins) to be defined properly.

I see someone called "samtech" asked about this exact same function a couple of days ago;

```
function sun_link_field_process($element, $form_state, $complete_form) {
  $instance = **field_widget_instance**($element, $form_state);
  $settings = $instance['settings'];
  $attributes = isset($element['#value']['attributes']) ? $element['#value']['attributes'] : $settings['attributes'];
  $element['attributes']['link_classes'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Custom link classes'),
    '#description' => t('A space delimited list of custom classes to be applied to the link.'),
    '#default_value' => isset($attributes['link_classes']) ? $attributes['link_classes'] : '',
    '#field_prefix' => 'class="',
    '#field_suffix' => '"',
  );
  return $element;
}
```

Assuming this is the full function, just look to [/core/modules/image/src/Plugin/Field/FieldWidget/ImageWidget.php](https://github.com/drupal/drupal/blob/9.1.x/core/modules/image/src/Plugin/Field/FieldWidget/ImageWidget.php) for how to apply a "process" on a form widget element in D9.  But note, that your function exists at all suggests that none of the rest of the field is defined correctly either?

```
  /**
   * Form API callback: Processes an image_image field element.
   *
   * Expands the image_image type to include the alt and title fields.
   *
   * This method is assigned as a #process callback in formElement() method.
   */
  public static function process($element, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form) {
```